# What HTTP code to return for a POST to a resource URI which depends on the responsiveness or accessibility of another related object?

Tags: rest, http, error-handling, restful-architecture

I am performing a POST to a resource URI. But the success of this operation depends on the responsiveness or accessibility of another related object. If that object is not responsive or inaccessible, the operation needs to return failure. What HTTP code should I choose in this case?

I am currently brainstorming on the following codes, but could not arrive at the right one:

1. 404 NOT FOUND - This represents "not found" for the resource URI, and not a related inaccessible entity.
2. 412 PRECONDITION FAILED - Applicable only for conditional requests with one or more header fields indicating a precondition - I dont need to provide any.

I am not able to find or zero onto a specific  HTTP code.

Comment: http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/

Comment: @jonrsharpe Excellent link. Thanks very much. Based on the responses and the available information, 409 looks more appropriate. But I think the reasoning-out for/against 409 ("Request incompatible with a previous request?") in the link is a little too specific compared to whats provided in the RFC. But thanks for a good article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#status.409:

"6.5.8 409 Conflict

The 409 (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target resource. This code is used in situations where the user might be able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request. The server SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user to recognize the source of the conflict."

Comment: Thanks, I think this looks more appropriate. I just need to provide a way for the user to monitor and manage this inaccessible entity via the response payload.

Answer (score 0):

Picking the right status code is always tricky. If you return a status code like 404 for example, debugging can become derailed because someone may not be sure if it's because the URL actually doesn't exist or if it's because of some other reason internally.

Usually the caller only needs to know a few things:

- Did the endpoint exist? If not, 404 NOT FOUND
- Was my request properly formed and did it pass validation? If not, 400 BAD REQUEST
- Was my request denied because of improper authentication? If not, 401 or 403 depending on the context (there is a subtle difference)
- Did my request fail because of something out of my control? If so, 500 INTERNAL ERROR

Typically I try to separate the response from the service's logic. If you want to be more specific as to exactly what happened (in your example a dependency is not responsive), returning a bit of JSON that describes in more detail what the problem was is would be a more appropriate place for that as opposed to using the http status code to describe a specific error on the service side.

So in your case, I think 500 is the most appropriate. The caller just knows that something went wrong and there's nothing it can do about it, and it can handle that condition however it needs to. If the caller needs to know more about what happened, use a JSON response to convey that.

Comment: This is not an "internal error" condition. This is just a state of the system that is not satisfying the POST operation. So to me, this is looks more like a "Conflict" 409.

Answer (score 0):

Lets check the candidates:

**404**: always an option but as the same request will sometimes fail or success this will create a flickering behavior which is not what a client would expect when getting 404.

**412**: RFC 2616 says: "The precondition given in one or more of the request-header fields" - this is not the reason for the failure.

**417**: similar to 412: "The expectation given in an Expect request-header field could not be met by this server"

**503**: "The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the server."

Nothing seems to be perfect but I would choose **503** as it represents the temporary problem best and guides the client to do a retry.

Comment: 503 looks appropriate when the server is overloaded or in maintenance state. But both are not applicable for this situation.

Comment: It does not fit perfectly but you should choose a state the client would handle in an appropriate way and 503 will make retry valid. But 409 Conflict is also a valid idea.

Answer (score -3):

List of HTTP status codes

- 1xx Informational
- 2xx Success
- 3xx Redirection
- 4xx Client Error
- 5xx Server Error

Refer [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) :

103 Checkpoint

> Used in the resumable requests proposal to resume aborted PUT or POST requests.

420 Method Failure (Spring Framework)

> A deprecated response used by the Spring Framework when a method has failed.
>   420 Enhance Your Calm (Twitter)
>   Returned by version 1 of the Twitter Search and Trends API when the client is being rate limited; versions 1.1 and later use the 429 Too Many Requests response code instead.

450 Blocked by Windows Parental Controls (Microsoft)

> A Microsoft extension. This error is given when Windows Parental Controls are turned on and are blocking access to the given webpage.

498 Invalid Token (Esri)

> Returned by ArcGIS for Server. A code of 498 indicates an expired or otherwise invalid token.

499 Token Required (Esri)

> Returned by ArcGIS for Server. A code of 499 indicates that a token is required but was not submitted.

499 Request has been forbidden by antivirus

> Produced by some programs such as Wget when a malicious site is intercepted.

509 Bandwidth Limit Exceeded (Apache Web Server/cPanel)

> The server has exceeded the bandwidth specified by the server administrator; > this is often used by shared hosting providers to limit the bandwidth of customers.

530 Site is frozen

> Used by the Pantheon web platform to indicate a site that has been frozen due to inactivity.

Comment: I referred to the wiki and all these error codes prior to asking this question. Those sources and your list unfortunately does not help. But thanks for caring to respond.

Comment: OK, I apologize for not help you